# Class with generic types compiles in Eclipse but not in GitHub Actions

Tags: java, generics

I'm trying to fix CI errors in the GH Actions build for my computer game, MultiMachineBuilder,
but the error does not appear anywhere in Eclipse.

Full erroring code: https://github.com/MultiMachineBuilder/MultiMachineBuilder/blob/master/src/mmb/content/modular/chest/ModularChest.java and https://github.com/MultiMachineBuilder/MultiMachineBuilder/blob/master/src/mmb/content/stn/block/STNFramework.java

 Erroring code (minimal):

```
public abstract class ChestCore<Tinv extends SaveInventory> extends PartEntity implements BlockCore<ChestCore<Tinv>>{
    ...
}
```

```
public class CoreSlot<Tblock extends ModularBlock<Tblock, ?, Tcore, ?>, Tcore extends BlockCore<Tcore>> extends Slot<Tcore>{
    ...
}
```

```
import mmb.engine.inv.SaveInventory;
public final class ModularChest extends BlockEntityData implements
ModularBlock<ModularChest, BlockModuleUniversal, ChestCore<? extends SaveInventory>, Object> {
    //Core
    @NN private static Class<ChestCore<? extends SaveInventory>> cls1 = MMBUtils.classcast(ChestCore.class);
    @NN private final CoreSlot<ModularChest, ChestCore<? extends SaveInventory>> core = new CoreSlot<>(this, cls1);
    @NN private final SidedSlotHelper<ModularChest, BlockModuleUniversal> ssh = new SidedSlotHelper<>(BlockModuleUniversal.class, this);
}
```

The equality constraints seem compatible, despite the error:

 `mmb.content.modular.chest.ChestCore<capture#2 of ? extends mmb.engine.inv.SaveInventory>` and

 `mmb.content.modular.chest.ChestCore<? extends mmb.engine.inv.SaveInventory>`

Error log:

```
Error:  Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.10.1:compile (default-compile) on project MMB: Compilation failure: Compilation failure: 
Error:  /home/runner/work/MultiMachineBuilder/MultiMachineBuilder/src/mmb/content/modular/chest/ModularChest.java:[31,59] type argument mmb.content.modular.chest.ChestCore<? extends mmb.engine.inv.SaveInventory> is not within bounds of type-variable Tcore
Error:  /home/runner/work/MultiMachineBuilder/MultiMachineBuilder/src/mmb/content/modular/chest/ModularChest.java:[50,59] type argument mmb.content.modular.chest.ChestCore<? extends mmb.engine.inv.SaveInventory> is not within bounds of type-variable Tcore
Error:  /home/runner/work/MultiMachineBuilder/MultiMachineBuilder/src/mmb/content/modular/chest/ModularChest.java:[50,93] cannot infer type arguments for mmb.content.modular.Slot.CoreSlot<>
Error:    reason: inference variable Tcore has incompatible equality constraints mmb.content.modular.chest.ChestCore<capture#1 of ? extends mmb.engine.inv.SaveInventory>,mmb.content.modular.chest.ChestCore<? extends mmb.engine.inv.SaveInventory>
Error:  /home/runner/work/MultiMachineBuilder/MultiMachineBuilder/src/mmb/content/stn/block/STNFramework.java:[38,59] type argument mmb.content.modular.chest.ChestCore<? extends mmb.engine.inv.SaveInventory> is not within bounds of type-variable Tcore
Error:  /home/runner/work/MultiMachineBuilder/MultiMachineBuilder/src/mmb/content/stn/block/STNFramework.java:[69,59] type argument mmb.content.modular.chest.ChestCore<? extends mmb.engine.inv.SaveInventory> is not within bounds of type-variable Tcore
Error:  /home/runner/work/MultiMachineBuilder/MultiMachineBuilder/src/mmb/content/stn/block/STNFramework.java:[69,93] cannot infer type arguments for mmb.content.modular.Slot.CoreSlot<>
Error:    reason: inference variable Tcore has incompatible equality constraints mmb.content.modular.chest.ChestCore<capture#2 of ? extends mmb.engine.inv.SaveInventory>,mmb.content.modular.chest.ChestCore<? extends mmb.engine.inv.SaveInventory>
```

I've tried both constrained and unconstrained types:

```java
import mmb.engine.inv.SaveInventory;
public final class ModularChest extends BlockEntityData implements
ModularBlock<ModularChest, BlockModuleUniversal, ChestCore<? extends SaveInventory>, Object> {
    //Core
    @NN private static Class<ChestCore<? extends SaveInventory>> cls1 = MMBUtils.classcast(ChestCore.class);
    @NN private final CoreSlot<ModularChest, ChestCore<? extends SaveInventory>> core = new CoreSlot<>(this, cls1);
```

and

```java
import mmb.engine.inv.SaveInventory;
public final class ModularChest extends BlockEntityData implements
ModularBlock<ModularChest, BlockModuleUniversal, ChestCore<?>, Object> {
    //Core
    @NN private static Class<ChestCore<?> cls1 = MMBUtils.classcast(ChestCore.class);
    @NN private final CoreSlot<ModularChest, ChestCore<?> core = new CoreSlot<>(this, cls1);
```

, but the error still persists

Comment: What you have posted is far from a [mcve]. You should at least include the declarations of `ChestCore` and `CoreSlot`.

Comment: @Sweeper I've added missinng definitions